# Disable multiple checkboxes in dropdowns based on another selected checkbox of a first dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Disable multiple checkboxes in dropdowns based on another selected checkbox of a first dropdown
I have multi-select 3 drop downs. All three dropdowns have same values. I want to disable second and third drop-down values based on the selected value of first. That means, when the user selected two options in first drop-down, the checkbox which contains those selected values in the first drop-down should get disabled in second drop-down and third drop-down and when user selected three options in second drop-down, the checkbox which contains those selected values in first drop-down, as well as second drop-down, should get disabled in third drop-down.

Priority is First drop-down than second and third respectively.

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.fSelect = function(options) {

    if ('string' === typeof options) {
      var settings = options;
    } else {
      var settings = $.extend({
        placeholder: 'Select some options',
        numDisplayed: 3,
        overflowText: '{n} selected',
        searchText: 'Search',
        showSearch: true,
        optionFormatter: false
      }, options);
    }


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function fSelect(select, settings) {
      this.$select = $(select);
      this.settings = settings;
      this.create();
    }


    /**
     * Prototype class
     */
    fSelect.prototype = {
      create: function() {
        this.settings.multiple = this.$select.is('[multiple]');
        var multiple = this.settings.multiple ? ' multiple' : '';
        this.$select.wrap('<div class="fs-wrap' + multiple + '" tabindex="0" />');
        this.$select.before('<div class="fs-label-wrap"><div class="fs-label">' + this.settings.placeholder + '</div><span class="fs-arrow"></span></div>');
        this.$select.before('<div class="fs-dropdown hidden"><div class="fs-options"></div></div>');
        this.$select.addClass('hidden');
        this.$wrap = this.$select.closest('.fs-wrap');
        this.$wrap.data('id', window.fSelect.num_items);
        window.fSelect.num_items++;
        this.reload();
      },

      reload: function() {
        if (this.settings.showSearch) {
          var search = '<div class="fs-search"><input type="search" placeholder="' + this.settings.searchText + '" /></div>';
          this.$wrap.find('.fs-dropdown').prepend(search);
        }
        this.idx = 0;
        this.optgroup = 0;
        this.selected = [].concat(this.$select.val()); // force an array
        var choices = this.buildOptions(this.$select);
        this.$wrap.find('.fs-options').html(choices);
        this.reloadDropdownLabel();
      },

      destroy: function() {
        this.$wrap.find('.fs-label-wrap').remove();
        this.$wrap.find('.fs-dropdown').remove();
        this.$select.unwrap().removeClass('hidden');
      },

      buildOptions: function($element) {
        var $this = this;

        var choices = '';
        $element.children().each(function(i, el) {
          var $el = $(el);

          if ('optgroup' == $el.prop('nodeName').toLowerCase()) {
            choices += '<div class="fs-optgroup-label" data-group="' + $this.optgroup + '">' + $el.prop('label') + '</div>';
            choices += $this.buildOptions($el);
            $this.optgroup++;
          } else {
            var val = $el.prop('value');

            // exclude the first option in multi-select mode
            if (0 < $this.idx || '' != val || !$this.settings.multiple) {
              var disabled = $el.is(':disabled') ? ' disabled' : '';
              var selected = -1 < $.inArray(val, $this.selected) ? ' selected' : '';
              var group = ' g' + $this.optgroup;
              var row = '<div class="fs-option' + selected + disabled + group + '" data-value="' + val + '" data-index="' + $this.idx + '"><span class="fs-checkbox"><i></i></span><div class="fs-option-label">' + $el.html() + '</div></div>';

              if ('function' === typeof $this.settings.optionFormatter) {
                row = $this.settings.optionFormatter(row);
              }

              choices += row;
              $this.idx++;
            }
          }
        });

        return choices;
      },

      reloadDropdownLabel: function() {
        var settings = this.settings;
        var labelText = [];

        this.$wrap.find('.fs-option.selected').each(function(i, el) {
          labelText.push($(el).find('.fs-option-label').text());
        });

        if (labelText.length < 1) {
          labelText = settings.placeholder;
        } else if (labelText.length > settings.numDisplayed) {
          labelText = settings.overflowText.replace('{n}', labelText.length);
        } else {
          labelText = labelText.join(', ');
        }

        this.$wrap.find('.fs-label').html(labelText);
        this.$wrap.toggleClass('fs-default', labelText === settings.placeholder);
        this.$select.change();
      }
    }


    /**
     * Loop through each matching element
     */
    return this.each(function() {
      var data = $(this).data('fSelect');

      if (!data) {
        data = new fSelect(this, settings);
        $(this).data('fSelect', data);
      }

      if ('string' === typeof settings) {
        data[settings]();
      }
    });
  }


  /**
   * Events
   */
  window.fSelect = {
    'num_items': 0,
    'active_id': null,
    'active_el': null,
    'last_choice': null,
    'idx': -1
  };

  $(document).on('click', '.fs-option:not(.hidden, .disabled)', function(e) {
    var $wrap = $(this).closest('.fs-wrap');
    var do_close = false;

    if ($wrap.hasClass('multiple')) {
      var selected = [];

      // shift + click support
      if (e.shiftKey && null != window.fSelect.last_choice) {
        var current_choice = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'));
        var addOrRemove = !$(this).hasClass('selected');
        var min = Math.min(window.fSelect.last_choice, current_choice);
        var max = Math.max(window.fSelect.last_choice, current_choice);

        for (i = min; i <= max; i++) {
          $wrap.find('.fs-option[data-index=' + i + ']')
            .not('.hidden, .disabled')
            .each(function() {
              $(this).toggleClass('selected', addOrRemove);
            });
        }
      } else {
        window.fSelect.last_choice = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'));
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
      }

      $wrap.find('.fs-option.selected').each(function(i, el) {
        selected.push($(el).attr('data-value'));
      });
    } else {
      var selected = $(this).attr('data-value');
      $wrap.find('.fs-option').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      do_close = true;
    }

    $wrap.find('select').val(selected);
    $wrap.find('select').fSelect('reloadDropdownLabel');

    // fire an event
    $(document).trigger('fs:changed', $wrap);

    if (do_close) {
      closeDropdown($wrap);
    }
  });

  $(document).on('keyup', '.fs-search input', function(e) {
    if (40 == e.which) { // down
      $(this).blur();
      return;
    }

    var $wrap = $(this).closest('.fs-wrap');
    var matchOperators = /[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g;
    var keywords = $(this).val().replace(matchOperators, '\\$&');

    $wrap.find('.fs-option, .fs-optgroup-label').removeClass('hidden');

    if ('' != keywords) {
      $wrap.find('.fs-option').each(function() {
        var regex = new RegExp(keywords, 'gi');
        if (null === $(this).find('.fs-option-label').text().match(regex)) {
          $(this).addClass('hidden');
        }
      });

      $wrap.find('.fs-optgroup-label').each(function() {
        var group = $(this).attr('data-group');
        var num_visible = $(this).closest('.fs-options').find('.fs-option.g' + group + ':not(.hidden)').length;
        if (num_visible < 1) {
          $(this).addClass('hidden');
        }
      });
    }

    setIndexes($wrap);
  });

  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var $el = $(e.target);
    var $wrap = $el.closest('.fs-wrap');

    if (0 < $wrap.length) {

      // user clicked another fSelect box
      if ($wrap.data('id') !== window.fSelect.active_id) {
        closeDropdown();
      }

      // fSelect box was toggled
      if ($el.hasClass('fs-label') || $el.hasClass('fs-arrow')) {
        var is_hidden = $wrap.find('.fs-dropdown').hasClass('hidden');

        if (is_hidden) {
          openDropdown($wrap);
        } else {
          closeDropdown($wrap);
        }
      }
    }
    // clicked outside, close all fSelect boxes
    else {
      closeDropdown();
    }
  });

  $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    var $wrap = window.fSelect.active_el;
    var $target = $(e.target);

    // toggle the dropdown on space
    if ($target.hasClass('fs-wrap')) {
      if (32 == e.which) {
        $target.find('.fs-label').trigger('click');
        return;
      }
    }
    // preserve spaces during search
    else if (0 < $target.closest('.fs-search').length) {
      if (32 == e.which) {
        return;
      }
    } else if (null === $wrap) {
      return;
    }

    if (38 == e.which) { // up
      e.preventDefault();

      $wrap.find('.fs-option.hl').removeClass('hl');

      var $current = $wrap.find('.fs-option[data-index=' + window.fSelect.idx + ']');
      var $prev = $current.prevAll('.fs-option:not(.hidden, .disabled)');

      if ($prev.length > 0) {
        window.fSelect.idx = parseInt($prev.attr('data-index'));
        $wrap.find('.fs-option[data-index=' + window.fSelect.idx + ']').addClass('hl');
        setScroll($wrap);
      } else {
        window.fSelect.idx = -1;
        $wrap.find('.fs-search input').focus();
      }
    } else if (40 == e.which) { // down
      e.preventDefault();

      var $current = $wrap.find('.fs-option[data-index=' + window.fSelect.idx + ']');
      if ($current.length < 1) {
        var $next = $wrap.find('.fs-option:not(.hidden, .disabled):first');
      } else {
        var $next = $current.nextAll('.fs-option:not(.hidden, .disabled)');
      }

      if ($next.length > 0) {
        window.fSelect.idx = parseInt($next.attr('data-index'));
        $wrap.find('.fs-option.hl').removeClass('hl');
        $wrap.find('.fs-option[data-index=' + window.fSelect.idx + ']').addClass('hl');
        setScroll($wrap);
      }
    } else if (32 == e.which || 13 == e.which) { // space, enter
      e.preventDefault();

      $wrap.find('.fs-option.hl').click();
    } else if (27 == e.which) { // esc
      closeDropdown($wrap);
    }
  });

  function setIndexes($wrap) {
    $wrap.find('.fs-option.hl').removeClass('hl');
    $wrap.find('.fs-search input').focus();
    window.fSelect.idx = -1;
  }

  function setScroll($wrap) {
    var $container = $wrap.find('.fs-options');
    var $selected = $wrap.find('.fs-option.hl');

    var itemMin = $selected.offset().top + $container.scrollTop();
    var itemMax = itemMin + $selected.outerHeight();
    var containerMin = $container.offset().top + $container.scrollTop();
    var containerMax = containerMin + $container.outerHeight();

    if (itemMax > containerMax) { // scroll down
      var to = $container.scrollTop() + itemMax - containerMax;
      $container.scrollTop(to);
    } else if (itemMin < containerMin) { // scroll up
      var to = $container.scrollTop() - containerMin - itemMin;
      $container.scrollTop(to);
    }
  }

  function openDropdown($wrap) {
    window.fSelect.active_el = $wrap;
    window.fSelect.active_id = $wrap.data('id');
    window.fSelect.initial_values = $wrap.find('select').val();
    $wrap.find('.fs-dropdown').removeClass('hidden');
    $wrap.addClass('fs-open');
    setIndexes($wrap);
  }

  function closeDropdown($wrap) {
    if ('undefined' == typeof $wrap && null != window.fSelect.active_el) {
      $wrap = window.fSelect.active_el;
    }
    if ('undefined' !== typeof $wrap) {
      // only trigger if the values have changed
      var initial_values = window.fSelect.initial_values;
      var current_values = $wrap.find('select').val();
      if (JSON.stringify(initial_values) != JSON.stringify(current_values)) {
        $(document).trigger('fs:closed', $wrap);
      }
    }

    $('.fs-wrap').removeClass('fs-open');
    $('.fs-dropdown').addClass('hidden');
    window.fSelect.active_el = null;
    window.fSelect.active_id = null;
    window.fSelect.last_choice = null;
  }

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.fs-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 340px;
}

.fs-label-wrap {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: default;
}

.fs-label-wrap,
.fs-dropdown {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.fs-label-wrap .fs-label {
  padding: 6px 22px 6px 8px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fs-arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.fs-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 340px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.fs-dropdown .fs-options {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.fs-search input {
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  outline: none;
  padding: 4px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.fs-option,
.fs-search,
.fs-optgroup-label {
  padding: 6px 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  cursor: default;
}

.fs-option:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.fs-search {
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.fs-option {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fs-option.disabled {
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: default;
}

.fs-option.hl {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.fs-wrap.multiple .fs-option {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.fs-wrap.multiple .fs-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.fs-wrap.multiple .fs-option .fs-checkbox i {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #aeaeae;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.fs-wrap.multiple .fs-option.selected .fs-checkbox i {
  background-color: rgb(17, 169, 17);
  border-color: transparent;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAGCAYAAAD+Bd/7AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAABx0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgRmlyZXdvcmtzIENTNXG14zYAAABMSURBVAiZfc0xDkAAFIPhd2Kr1WRjcAExuIgzGUTIZ/AkImjSofnbNBAfHvzAHjOKNzhiQ42IDFXCDivaaxAJd0xYshT3QqBxqnxeHvhunpu23xnmAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.fs-optgroup-label {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Create Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- The below url are required for dropdown -->
  <link href="http://localhost/Performance/Test/css/fselect.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://localhost/Performance/Test/js/fSelect.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function($) {
      $(function() {
        $('#project_manager').fSelect();
        $('#test_engineer').fSelect();
        $('#viewer').fSelect();
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <label>Select Project Manager :</label><br/>
  <select id="project_manager" name="project_manager[]" multiple="multiple"><br/>
    <optgroup label="pm">
       <option value="1">Test 1</option>
       <option value="2">Test 2</option>
       <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select><br/>
  <label>Select Test Engineer :</label><br/>
  <select id="test_engineer" name="test_engineer[]" multiple="multiple"><br/>
    <optgroup label="te">
       <option value="1">Test 1</option>
       <option value="2">Test 2</option>
       <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select><br/>
  <label>Select Viewer :</label><br/>
  <select id="viewer" name="viewer[]" multiple="multiple"><br/>
    <optgroup label="viewer">
       <option value="1">Test 1</option>
       <option value="2">Test 2</option>
       <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select><br/>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @TakitIsy localhost links are given. so it wont work.

Comment: Where are those checkboxes?

Comment: I have edited you can see now

Comment: you need to write a function for that. On first dropdown lost focus. You have to do that.

Comment: @Deepak Kumar, I am beginner in jQuery. I tried it.For single select but for multi select it is not working.

Comment: For single select, I have tried like this without using css and js above code,

Comment: I have updated that in the code,But to try that I need to remove js and css

Comment: As I see this dropdown list is build using CSS so, you need to toggle between on selected css property. and apply show and hide logic.@DeepakN

Comment: I have done it without using above css and js code, I am not able to add this code with above css and js